# How to properly sync multithreading with mutex in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, process

How should i properly sync threads with mutex?
I'm trying a simple "sync" using mutex, something really small, like just printing a string containing the number of the thread. snippet here:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_RESOURCE 5
#define NO_THREADS 5
int res_available = MAX_RESOURCE;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
struct count { int no;};

void *
use_res(void *v) {
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
 struct count *p = (struct count *) v;
 printf("--thread no %d :" p->nr);
 return NULL;
}


int main(){
  pthread_t thr[NO_THREADS];
  pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
  for(int i=0; i<N0_THREADS; i++){
     struct count *c = malloc(sizeof(struct count));
     c->nr = i;
     pthread_create(thr[i], NULL, use_res, c))
     }
  for(int i=0; i<NO_THREADS; i++) {
     pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
     }
  return 0;
}
```

Fact is, when executed, the sync doesn't actually occur, actually, what it does occur, is still that "race condition", making the program to print something else everytime.

My question is, how do i stop this race condition? I don't know if i'm using correctly this `lock` and `unlock` thing.

Comment: What is "sync threads"?

Comment: If you want all threads to be created before starting (pretty much) simultaneously: lock the mutex from the main thread, spawn other threads that all attempt the lock and thus have to wait, when all threads have started, unlock the mutex from main, and then all threads can race for it. Make sure that every thread also properly unlocks the mutex.

Comment: What do U mean by sync U may be confusing mutex locks with conditional variables.

Comment: In `use_res`, I think you need a `pthread_mutex_unlock` at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to release mutex when your thread function finish, also add `\n` at the end of print, because stdout will buffer this text:

```
void *
use_res(void *v) {
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
 struct count *p = (struct count *) v;
 printf("--thread no %d :\n" p->no);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
 return NULL;
}
```